# Передача POST параметров программе

Tags: post, java, сокет

Пишу программку на java - её цель принимать и обрабатывать запросы. GET запросы принимает, параметры я могу достать, а вот с POST-запросом не знаю как быть, параметры просто не грузятся в input. Считываю данные из Socketa'а так:

```
is = socket.getInputStream();
// буффер данных в 64 килобайта
byte buf[] = new byte[64*1024];
// читаем 64кб от клиента, результат - кол-во реально принятых данных
int r = is.read(buf);
// создаём строку, содержащую полученую от клиента информацию
String ans = new String(buf, 0, r);
System.out.print(ans);
```

При выводе POST-параметры не выводятся, `Content-Length` изменяется. Что делать не понятно...

Возможно ли средствами Soсket'ов получать POST - параматры? И, если невозможно, чем лучше воспользоваться?

Comment: Вопрос обновил. За наводку спасибо.

Comment: @jekatigr, не занимайтесь изобретательством очередного деревянного велосипеда с квадратными колёсами :) Конечно, с помощью сокетов можно много чего сделать, но разбирать HTTP-запросы, особенно POST, это оно и есть. Одну ссылку уже дали, но если очень хочется заниматься ручным выпиливанием по глыбам гранита - смотрите в сторону интерфейса [ServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html)

Answer (score 2):

Чувствуется какая-то путаница. HTTP - это протокол. GET и POST - типы запросов. Сокет - низкоуровневая абстракция для работы с сетевыми соединениями.

Есть готовые библиотеки, позволяющие устанавливать HTTP-соединения, отправлять и получать запросы и т.п. Например Apache HttpComponents (http://hc.apache.org/).